# Swift Dictionary of string's array equality

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, equality

I'm trying to have a dictionary that have Strings as key and array of String as value.
Then I want to check if 2 of those dictionaries are equal like so:

```
let dicOfStringStringAr1: [String : [String]] = ["key1" : ["val", "for key 1"]]
let dicOfStringStringAr2: [String : [String]] = ["key1" : ["val", "for key 1"]]
if dicOfStringStringAr1 == dicOfStringStringAr2 {
    print("Dictionary of String Array")
}
```

But I get this error:

> error: binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '[String : [String]]' operands

But if the values are String instead of [String] it works.

```
let dicOfStringAr1: [String : String] = ["key1" : "val"]
let dicOfStringAr2: [String : String] = ["key1" : "val"]
if dicOfStringAr1 == dicOfStringAr2 {
    print("Dictionary of String Array")
}
```

I don't understand the problem.
Someone can explain what is the issue.

---

After looking at the default == Swift function for Dictionary

```
@warn_unused_result
public func ==<Key : Equatable, Value : Equatable>(lhs: [Key : Value], rhs: [Key : Value]) -> Bool
```

I realized that there is no definition where Value is represented as an array, and that the "generic" Value can't be resolve to a collection. (Not sure why).
So I made a == function that would have [Key : [Value]] parameters. And now the code work.

```
@warn_unused_result
public func ==<Key : Equatable, Value : Equatable>(lhs: [Key : [Value]], rhs: [Key : [Value]]) -> Bool {
    var result = lhs.count == rhs.count
    for (k, v) in lhs {
        guard let arValue = rhs[k] where result == true else {
            result = false
            break
        }

        result = v == arValue
    }

    return result
}
```

Can someone explain why in the Swift == implementation Value can't be resolve to a single item, being an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually makes sense. As you can see from the `==` function for type `<Key : Equatable, Value : Equatable>`, it requires `Value` to conform `Equatable`. By default, `Array` type doesn't conform to `Equatable`. **Note, this doesn't mean you cannot compare two arrays using `==`.**

```
[1, 2, 3] == ["a", "b", "c"] // false.
```

Conforming to `Equatable` means you can use `==` but not vice verse.

You can of course extend the `Array` type to conform to `Equatable`.

```
extension Array: Equatable {}
// Implement the following method.
public func ==<T: CollectionType, U: CollectionType>(lhs: T, rhs: U) -> Bool {}
```

---

**Update**

I would say it's not possible right now to implement a plausible `==` for `Array`. (It might be possible in the [future swift version](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151214/002300.html))

For your specific case, I would say the following method is fair enough. When you have a custom `struct`, just make sure it conforms `Equatable`.

```
public func  ==<Key : Equatable, Value : CollectionType where Value.Generator.Element: Equatable>(lhs: [Key : Value], rhs: [Key : Value]) -> Bool {
    guard lhs.keys.elementsEqual(rhs.keys) else { return false }

    for (key, value) in lhs {
        if !value.elementsEqual(rhs[key]!) { return false }
    }

    return true
}
```

Example would be:

```
struct Number: Equatable {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
}

func ==(lhs: Number, rhs: Number) -> Bool {
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y
}

let dicOfStringStringAr1: [String : [Number]] = ["key1" : [Number(x: 1, y: 2), Number(x: 1, y: 2)]]
let dicOfStringStringAr2: [String : [Number]] = ["key1" : [Number(x: 1, y: 2), Number(x: 1, y: 2)]]
if dicOfStringStringAr1 == dicOfStringStringAr2 {
    print("Dictionary of String Array") // "Dictionary of String Array"
}
```

Comment: interesting Idea, how would you implement your == function to be generic and type safe. I've tried `==<T: CollectionType, U: CollectionType where T.Generator.Element: Equatable, T.Generator.Element == U.Generator.Element>` to limit the reach of the function to only array that could be compare with == but had to also have `==<T: CollectionType, U: CollectionType>` for protocol compliance. The problem is that the last one is use so I always get false.

Comment: I will post an other question later concerning this, to explore the possibility of having this working in a generic way. I will put a new comment when it's done in case you have ideas about it.

Comment: Thanks, this is not as generic as I would like this to be, but it is working in a broader manner than my solution. As an example I was not able to have it work with this dictionary `[String : [String : String]]` structure.

Comment: Thanks again, I've however run into a problem with this implementation, it make equality between 2 Set Ambiguous...

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, you can check if these dictionaries are equal by converting your dictionary to a NSDictionary and using its method `isEqualToDictionary`. For example:

```
if NSDictionary(dictionary: dicOfStringStringAr1).isEqualToDictionary(dicOfStringStringAr2) {
    print("Dictionary of String Array")
}
```

Comment: this is a walk around that will only work with objects, if I have an array of struct this code will break. I'm looking for a more generic solution.

Comment: That would be useful info to put in your question

Comment: Thanks, but I tough that "Someone have some light about what is the issue." was making it clear that I was more interested in understanding the issue than having a walk around. I've updated the question. I hope it will discard ambiguity.

Comment: I think I've read something about matt saying it's because it gets automatically bridged to `NSString` etc. But if you want to know for sure, you could dig into his comments or posts where he has answered a few times.